# Double amt of Current Balance getting displayed in my simple web project

Tags: java, mysql, html, jsp

the code :

```
public static int getBalance()
{         
    List <Integer> sum = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int balance=0;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/money","root","cpp");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from account");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())
        {
            sum.add(Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)));
            for(int i:sum)
            {
                balance += i;   
            }

        }
    }
}
```

when amount is displayed it has been added double time 
 eg if 2000 is only the current amount the current balance is 4000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing this once for every result that you find, so if you have two results, the amounts will be summed twice:

```
            for(int i:sum)
             {
                 balance+=i;

             }
```

Try moving that block out of the `while` statement. You can learn more about `while` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Done tysm once again